# Is it appropriate to use eval() on JavaScript expressions?

Tags: javascript, publish-subscribe

I'm currently reading up on "Content-based publish/subscribe" design patterns and in one of the implementations it suggests subscribing to an event using expressions in string form ie. `eventMiddleware.on("foo===bar &&  bool",callback)`. 
However I'm not quite sure how to handle the string expression middleware side.

I'm constantly reading about how eval is "evil" and that I shouldn't use it, but is it appropriate in this case? Is there a better method? or should I just simply stay away from registering events with expressions entirely?

Comment: `simply stay away from registering events with expressions entirely` if you need an expression checked, do it at the beginning of your handler and terminate (`return;`)if required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `"foo===bar &&  bool"` is produced server-side just replace it with `function (x) { return x === bar && whatever-you-need; }`. Code your way around so that you evaluate the function by just calling it. You won't need eval at all if you can get this far.

The predicate is a *guard*. Say you define it this way:

```
function on(guard, callback)
{
}
```

Then, in your pattern, the message dispatcher should just do this:

```
if (tyepof(guard) === "FUNCTION" && guard(arg))
{
    callback(arg);
}
```

I hope this is comprehensible.

Comment: Sweet! Exactly what I was looking for thanks:) and now I can .call it with the publisher if I wanted or something similiar

Comment: No, you don't need to `.call` it, just *call* it :) I show you in a minute, I update my answer then you're free to accept it :)

Comment: Ooh okay I sort of get it, but what is args? Is it entirely generated from the publisher because ideally I'd like the guard to check properties within the publisher which is why I had the Idea to 'guard.call(publisher)' or just 'guard(publisher)' but it seems you might have something more...

Comment: The guard function requires variables to evaluate if the callback is called or not. The publisher will have to pass those values to the guard function. I wrote `arg` as a placeholder for whatever you have.